# java object serialization readObject/defaultReadObject

Tags: java, serialization

What's the difference between `readObject` and `defaultReadObject` in the `ObjectInputStream` class? I can't seem to find very much information on the difference.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`defaultReadObject()` invokes the default deserialization mechanism, and is used when you define the `readObject()` method on your `Serializable` class. In other words, when you have custom deserialization logic, you can still get back to the default serialization, which will deserialize your non-static, non-transient fields. For example:

```
public class SomeClass implements Serializable {
    private String fld1;
    private int fld2;
    private transient String fld3; 
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
         throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
         stream.defaultReadObject(); //fills fld1 and fld2;
         fld3 = Configuration.getFooConfigValue();
    }
]
```

---

On the other hand, `readObject()` is used when you create the `ObjectInputStream`, externally from the deserialized object, and want to read an object that was previously serialized:

```
ObojectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(aStreamWithASerializedObject);
Object foo = (Foo) stream.readObject();
```

Comment: @Aizaz you can't. Just catch it.

Comment: so if we write `readObject()` method without `stream.defaultReadObject();` its like `readexternal()` ?