# Deserializing a singleton in java

Tags: java, serialization

I am going through Effective Java, and came across this example.

```
class Elvis implements Serializable {
    public static final Elvis  inst = new Elvis();
    private Elvis() {
        System.out.println("In elvis constructor ");
    }

    public static Elvis getInstance() {
        return inst;
    }
}
```

According to the book, when i deserialize, a new ELVIS object should be constructed, but i see the constructor is not called at the time of deserialization?

Here is my code which serializes, and deserializes.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myserial1.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
Elvis e = Elvis.getInstance();
System.out.println(" e = "+e.getInstance());

oos.writeObject(e);

System.out.println("Serialization done.");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myserial1.txt");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
Elvis el = (Elvis) ois.readObject();
System.out.println(" el = "+el.getInstance());
```

I See both e and e1 are priting the same reference, and constructor is invoked only once.

Am i misunderstanding the concept here?

Please help.

Comment: Deserializaation implies you can do it more than once and this breaks the concept of a singleton.  It is not that you can't do it but what ever you do it's going to be a hack.

Comment: JBoss Smart cloning seems to reuse final fields, maybe this is the better option for you? http://www.jboss.org/serialization

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During serialization no constructor is called, fields initialized by deserialization process or [`readObject()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119181/java-object-serialization-readobject-defaultreadobject) (if you add this method into your class). If you want to implement a serializable singleton, you should additionally add `readResolve()` method as it described [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-with-examples#serialization-and-singleton).

---

PS. 
Keep in mind that `getInstance()` is a static method of class `Elvis`, so such calls as `e.getInstance()` and `el.getInstance()` are equals to `Elvis.getInstance()`.

Comment: from the book --"To maintain the singleton guarantee, you
have to declare all instance fields transient and provide a readResolve method
(Item 77). Otherwise, each time a serialized instance is deserialized, a new
instance will be created, leading, in the case of our example, to spurious Elvis
sightings. To prevent this, add this readResolve method to the Elvis class". According to the author, if i dont implement readResolve(), singletong is broken. But i see its not broken, and i am getting the same object(reference is same). This is what i fail to understand.

Comment: @venkataratnam
"But i see its not broken, and i am getting the same object(reference is same)".

Without "readResolve()" method "el" **is** **not** the same with "e", which is just "Elvis.getInstance()". You can test it by adding "System.out.println(el == e);" at the end of your program.

Answer (score 1):

> Am i misunderstanding the concept here?

What you are misunderstanding is that a constructor creates an object. No it doesn't. Constructor just initializes the object. Now, deserialization need not invoke the constructor, as it already has the state of the serialized object, and that is what it has to provide us.

However, if in the hierarchy of serializable class, there is some non-serializable class, then it's constructor would be invoked to initialize the state in that class, as it has not been serialized.

You can go through the [Serialization Specification.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
According to the book, when i deserialize, a new ELVIS object should be constructed,
but i see the constructor is not called at the time of deserialization?
```

First of all `Object creation and constructor invocation are two separate thing`. In normal scenario when you create an object with `new` keyword Object is first created and then constructor is invoked. You can see the bytecodes of any java class in which an object is created.

Now as for your question, in `Serialization` object is created like any other object and instead of running constructor values/state is restored using `reflection`. So basically values are read from stream(persistent storage is your case) and injected into the object using reflection.

Comment: Yes, just do not make the inst final and use Elvis.inst = (Elvis) ois.readObject(); is supporting that no constructor is beeing called! The result is: In elvis constructor 
 e = com.xxx.Elvis@1d5550d
Serialization done.
 el = com.xxx.Elvis@16fd0b7

Answer (score 0):

Since Read and Write operation both are executed in same jvm instance and 
class was already loaded for the read operation and the static fields are store atclass level So here static variable inst is never required to re instantiated
     `public static final Elvis  inst = new Elvis();`

So same reference are return which were attached with the class level